# How to get content or length of current console output?

Tags: r, console, output, cat, sapply

I'm looking for the functions get_output_content or at least get_output_length below, that would tell me how many characters were printed in the console.

```
test <- function(){
   cat("ab")
   cat("\b")
   cat("cd")
   c <- get_output_content() # "acd" (I'd be happy with "ab\bcd" as well)
   l <- get_output_length()  # 3
   return(list(c,l))
}
test()
```

In this example obviously I could easily count the characters in the input, but If I'm using other functions I may not. Can you help me build one or both of these functions ?

**EDIT to clarify:**

in my real situation, I cannot work upstream and count before, like in the proposed solutions, I need to count the displayed output at a given time without monitoring what's before.

here's a reproducible example looking more like what I want to achieve

```
library(pbapply)
my_files <- paste0(1000:1,".pdf")
work_on_pdf <- function(pdf_file){
  Sys.sleep(0.001)
}
report <- pbsapply(my_files,work_on_pdf) # the simple version, but I want to add the pdf name next to the bar to have more info about my progress
# so I tried this but it's not satisfying because it "eats" some of the current output of pbapply
report <- pbsapply(my_files,function(x){
    buffer_length <- 25
    work_on_pdf(x)
    catmsg <- paste0(c( # my additional message, which is in 3 parts: 
      rep("\b",buffer_length),          # (1) eat 25 characters
      x,                                # (2) print filename
      rep(" ",buffer_length-nchar(x))), # (3) print spaces to cover up what may have been printed before
      collapse="")
    cat(catmsg)
  })
```

if I was able to count what's in the console I could easily tweak my function to get something satisfying.

**NEW EDIT : FYI solution to example but not to general question:**

I could solve my precise issue with this, though it doesn't solve the general question, which is measuring the current output of the console when you don't have any other info.

```
library(pbapply)
my_files <- paste0(1000:1,".pdf")
work_on_pdf <- function(pdf_file){
  Sys.sleep(0.01)
}
pbsapply2 <- function(X,FUN,FUN2){
  # FUN2 will give the additional message  
  pbsapply(X,function(x){
    msg <- FUN2(x)
    cat(msg)
    output <- FUN(x)
    eraser <- paste0(c(  
      rep("\b",nchar(msg)),  # go back to position before additional message
      rep(" ",nchar(msg)),   # cover with blank spaces         
      rep("\b",nchar(msg))), # go back again to initial position
      collapse="")
    cat(eraser)
    return(output)
  })    
}
report <- pbsapply2(my_files,work_on_pdf,function(x) paste("filename:",x))
```

Comment: `nchar(capture.output(cat("ab\bcd")))` ?

Comment: or `sink()` may be more convenient here

Comment: I suppose I could sink it somewhere, count what I need to count, then unsink and reprint it on the console, at each iteration, that would work but that's a lot of overhead!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (?):

```
test <- function(){
  c <- paste0(capture.output(cat("ab")),
              capture.output(cat("\b")),
              capture.output(cat("cd")))
  n <- nchar(c)
  l <- length(c)
  return(list(c,n,l))
}
test()
```